# spool output to particular file from command prompt

Tags: sql-server, command, sqlcmd

[image]

I want to spool my output to  a particular file.
My database in SqlServer. I am entering code in command prompt like this:

[image]

First I am connecting to my data base like this:

```
sqlcmd -S SUPPORT2/SUPPORT2 -U sa -P solutions
```

SUPPORT2/SUPPORT2 is a my server name.
I choose my database name(vallett), then I am selecting Ename from EmployeeMaster_tbl.
I want to spool this output to a particular word file, how can I do this?

I tried somthing like this..but getting an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**-o** is a parameter for the call of sqlcmd a call could look like this

```
sqlcmd -S SUPPORT2/SUPPORT2 -U sa -P solutions -Q " SELECT Ename from Vallett.dbo.EmployeeMaster_tbl" -o C:\temp\test.txt
```

Make shure the destination file can be written (C:\txt1.txt might not be possible)

If you want to create the output file interactive you can use **:OUT** to redirect the output to a file and reset ist to **stdout**. An example could look like this:

```
 sqlcmd -S SUPPORT2/SUPPORT2 -U sa -P solutions 
 use Vallett
 GO
 :OUT C:\temp\test.txt
 SELECT Ename from dbo.EmployeeMaster_tbl
 GO
 :OUT stdout
```

Comment: while executing first command am getting this error in my test.txt  HResult 0x43, Level 16, State 1
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [67]. 
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Login timeout expired.

Comment: okey..sir..thanks for your help now worked fine everythng,,,i shall be very thank full to you

Answer (score 0):

Another option. 
If you don't need an interactive query, you can load a file with the query, and the following standard output redirection allows to add the output to a file with previous content.

```
sqlcmd -S SUPPORT2/SUPPORT2 -U sa -P solutions -i file_w_query.sql >> C:\temp\file_output.txt
```

And using a single symbol redirection, there is not difference with using  the parameter -o